# Should virtual dispatch happen when a virtual method is called within a virtual method using object?

Tags: c++, object, methods, overriding, virtual-functions

```
struct B
{
  virtual void bar () {}
  virtual void foo () { bar(); }
};

struct D : B
{
  virtual void bar () {}
  virtual void foo () {}
};
```

Now we call `foo()` using an object of `B` as,

```
B obj;
obj.foo();  // calls B::bar()
```

**Question**:
Should `bar()` will be resolved through `virtual` dispatch or it will be resolved using the static type of the object (i.e. `B`).

Comment: So what if I write `struct E : B { void bar() { std::cout << "hi\n"; }; ... E e; B *b = &e; b->foo();`. It is still the case that inside `B::foo()`, the type of `this` is `B*`, but it is no longer the case that the dynamic type of `*this` is `B`. You agree that in that situation, `B::foo()` must call `E::bar()`, don't you? So it can't be statically resolved in that case.

Comment: `Should it really matter if it is a virtual dispatch or whether the function call is resolved at compilation?` The behavior is well defined by the Standard & the compiler will do that whether through dynamic dispatch or not is an issue a smart compiler should be able to resolve judiciously. If you are thinking about performance optimization, then it seems like overkill.

Comment: @Steve, yes. the rule should still hold true. Because when you call `b->foo()`; it will choose `E::foo()` and it will go inside it. Now, again if you are calling `bar()` inside it, then it will resolve only `E::bar()`.

Comment: @iammilind: The implementation of `E::bar()` could choose to call `B::foo()`, so it is still perfectly possible to be inside of `B::foo()` and have the dynamic type of `*this` be `E`.

Comment: @iammilind: there is no `E::foo()`. That's the point of the example `E`, `B::foo` has to be capable of dealing with derived classes.

Comment: @Steve, you are correct. I realized that later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entirely up to the implementation. Nominally it's a virtual call, but you're not entitled to assume that the emitted code will actually perform an indirection through a vtable or similar.

If `foo()` is called on some arbitrary `B*`, then of course the code emitted for `foo()` needs to make a virtual call to `bar()`, since the referand might belong to a derived class.

This isn't an arbitrary `B*`, this is an object of dynamic type `B`. The result of a virtual or non-virtual call is exactly the same, so the compiler can do what it likes ("as-if" rule), and a conforming program can't tell the difference.

Specifically in this case, if the call to `foo` is inlined, then I'd have thought that the optimizer has every chance of de-virtualizing the call to `bar` inside it, since it knows exactly what's in the vtable (or equivalent) of `obj`. If the call isn't inlined, then it's going to use the "vanilla" code of `foo()`, which of course will need to do some kind of indirection since it's the same code used when the call is made on an arbitrary `B*`.

Comment: I will beg to differ here. What I feel that, once the control reaches inside `B::foo()`; **ideally** no call should be `virtually` dispatched. I will update this with detail in my question.

Comment: @iammilind: What do you mean, no call should be virtually dispatched? What if I write some code that creates an instance of `D` and and instance of `B`, and randomly assigns one of the two to a `B* b`, then calls `b->foo()`. How is the implementation supposed to avoid virtual dispatch when it calls `bar()` inside `foo()`? Unless you're counting on the fact that `B::bar()` and `D::bar()` both do nothing, in which case what if I write another TU that adds another derived class `E` that actually does something in `bar()`?

Comment: once you are inside `B::foo()`, compiler is sure that `this->Bar()` is of type `B*`. So it doesn't need to resolve `Bar()` at runtime, as `this` points to an object of `B`.

Comment: @iammilind The compiler is sure that the type of pointer is `B*` which says *absolutely nothing* about the dynamic type of `this`. It *still* has to make the virtual dispatch.

Comment: @iammilind: OK, I mentioned inlining in my answer. Another way for the compiler to achieve the de-virtualization would be for it to emit two different function bodies for `foo` (and any virtual function that calls a virtual function): one that is called when the call to `foo` is virtual, and a different one to call when the call to `foo` is non-virtual and the dynamic type of the object is `B`. The latter could de-virtualize the call. Have you checked whether your compiler does this?

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: I think I misunderstood your question. I'm pretty sure it depends on how smart the compiler's optimizer is. A naive implementation would of course still go through a virtual lookup. The only way to know for sure for a particular implementation is to compile the code and look at the disassembly to see if it's smart enough to make the direct call.

Original answer:

It will be virtually dispatched. This is more obvious when you consider that within a class method, a method call works out to something like `this->bar();`, making it obvious that a pointer is used to call the method, allowing to use the dynamic object type.

However in your example since you created a `B` it will of course call `B`'s version of the method.

Do note (as seen in a comment) that virtual dispatch doesn't happen inside constructors even using the implicit `this->`.

EDIT2 for your update:
That's not right at all. Calls within `B::foo()` cannot be generally bound statically (unless due to inlining the compiler *knows* the static type of the object). Just because it knows that it's being called on a `B*` says nothing about the real type of the object in question - it could be a `D*` and need virtual dispatch.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning the caveat that if `foo()` is called in the constructor of `B` then `B::foo()` gets called.

Comment: Ah, good catch. Yes, if the compiler can determine the dynamic type statically, which in the case of `obj.foo()` it can, it should be able to avoid the virtual dispatch.

Answer (score 2):

It must be a virtual call. The code that you're compiling cannot know if there's not a more-derived class that it actually is that has overridden the other function.

Note that this assumes that you're compiling these separately. If the compiler inlines the call to foo() (due to its static type being known) it'll also inline the call to bar().

Comment: Doesn't calling methods by object have a compile-time binding?

Comment: That's not required by the standard. It could still go through the virtual mechanism (arriving at the same result of course).

Comment: @Eric Z: It'll resolve the call to foo() statically. Inside foo(), it can't know in what exact context it's being used so the call to bar must be a virtual function call. Assuming of course, that it in fact cannot know what exact context it's being used in - hence my caveat about compiling separately.

Answer (score 2):

Answer: from the language point of view call to `bar()` inside `B::foo()` is resolved through virtual dispatch.

The bottom line is that from the point of view of C++ language, virtual dispatch *always* happens when you call a virtual method using its *non-qualified* name. When you use a *qualified* name of the method, the virtual dispatch does not happen. That means that the only way to suppress virtual dispatch in C++ is to use this syntax

```
some_object_ptr->SomeClass::some_method();
some_object.SomeClass::some_method();
```

In this case the dynamic type if the object on the left-hand side is ignored and the specific method is called directly.

In all other cases virtual dispatch does happen, as far as the language is concerned. I.e. the call is resolved in accordance with the dynamic type of the object. In other words, from the formal point of view, every time you call a virtual method through an immediate object, as in

```
B obj;
obj.foo();
```

the method is called through the "virtual dispatch" mechanism, regardless of context ("within a virtual method" or not - doesn't matter).

That's how it is in C++ language. Everything else is just optimizations made by compilers. As you probably know, most (if not all) compilers will generate a non-virtual call to a virtual method, when the call is performed through an immediate object. This is, of course, an obvious optimization, since the compiler knows that the static type of the object is the same as its dynamic type. Again, it doesn't depend on the context ("within a virtual method" or not - doesn't matter).

Inside a virtual method, the call can be made without specifying an object on the left hand side (as in your example), which really implies all calls have `this->` implicitly present on the left. The very same rules apply in this case as well. If you just call `bar()`, it stands for `this->bar()` and the call is dispatched virtually. If you call `B::bar()`, it stands for `this->B::bar()` and the call is dispatched non-virtually. Everything else will only depend on the optimization capabilities of the compiler.

What you are trying to say by "because, once you are inside `B::foo()`, it's sure that this is of type `B*` and not `D*`" is totally unclear to me. This statement misses the point. Virtual dispatch depends on the *dynamic* type of the *object*. Note: it depends on the type of `*this`, not on the type of `this`. It doesn't matter at all what the type of `this` is. What matters is the dynamic type of `*this`. When you are inside `B::foo`, it is still perfectly possible that the dynamic type of `*this` is `D` or something else. For which reason, the call to `bar()` has to be resolved dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

In this case:

```
B obj;
obj.foo();  // calls B::bar()
```

the compiler can optimize away the virtual dispatch since it knows that type of the actual object is `B`.

However, inside of `B::foo()` the call to `bar()` needs to use virtual dispatch generally (though the compiler might be able to inline the call and for *that particular call instance* could possibly optimize the virtual dispatch away again). Specifically, this statement you proposed:

> Irrespective of `foo()` is called using object or pointer/reference, all the calls inside any virtual `B::foo()` should be statically resolved. Because, once you are inside B::foo(), it's sure that this is of type `B*` and not `D*`

is not true.

Consider:

```
struct D2 : B
{
    // D2 does not override bar()
    virtual void foo () {
        cout << "hello from D2::bar()" << endl;
    }
};
```

Now if you had the following somewhere:

```
D2 test;

B& bref = test;

bref.foo();
```

That call to `foo()` would end up in `B::foo()`, but when `B::foo()` calls `bar()`, it needs to dispatch to `D2::bar()`.

Actually, now that I've typed this out, the `B&` is completely unnecessary for this example.